# How can i insert a comment form between parent comment and comment replies？

Tags: comments

[image: insert a parent comment reply form]

i want hide the comment reply，when user click the “2 replies” button will slide the replies，after slide out the replies i also want to show a comment form that people can post a reply easily.   anyone can help? Thank you so much.

Comment: no one can help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's correct way but maybe help somebody.

`function theme_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {`

```
$test_pid = array(); 
$test_cid = array();   
$keys = array_keys($variables['elements']['comments']['comments']);   

foreach ($keys as $k) {
    if (!is_numeric($k)) {
      continue;
    }
$pid = $variables['elements']['comments']['comments'][$k]['#comment']->pid;
$cid = $variables['elements']['comments']['comments'][$k]['#comment']->cid;
$test_pid[] += $pid;
$test_cid[] += $cid;
$variables['elements']['comments']['comments'][$pid]['#comment']->has_children = TRUE;    
$last = $k; 
}

// find all last children in comments
$Mcomment_children= array();
foreach($test_pid as $key=>$p){
    if (in_array($p, $test_cid)) {      
         $Mcomment_children[$p] = $test_cid[$key];          
    }
  }

  foreach($Mcomment_children as $last_children){
    $variables['elements']['comments']['comments'][$last_children]['#comment']->last_children = TRUE; 
  }    
  $variables['elements']['comments']['comments'][$last]['#comment']->last = TRUE;
}

In comment template file (comment.tpl) you can close div with children last. I used display suite but it's the same.

<?php if($comment->has_children !== true): ?>
</<?php print $ds_content_wrapper ?>>
  <?php endif;?>
  <?php if($comment->last_children === true): ?>
</<?php print $ds_content_wrapper ?>>
  <?php endif;?>
```